# I cannot pass the values of my combo box into an object. The error is 'incompatible types:Object cannot be converted to size'

Tags: java, swing, enums, combobox, jcombobox

I have a bunch of Enums in my Project which I have used for values in my combo boxes, but when I pass these values into my 'pizza' class, It gives me the error.

```
public class Pizza {
    private Size size;
    private Crust crust;
    private Sauce sauce;
    private Topping topping1;
    private Topping topping2;
    public Pizza(Size size,Crust crust, Sauce sauce,
                 Topping topping1,Topping topping2){
        this.size=size;
        this.crust=crust;
        this.sauce=sauce;
        this.topping1=topping1;
        this.topping2=topping2;
    }
    //blah blah
------------------------------------------
//This is one of my enums.
public enum Size {
    SMALL(9.45),MEDIUM(11.87),LARGE(15.9);
    private double size;
Size(double size){this.size=size;}
public double getSize(){return this.size;}
public String getSizeAsString(){return String.valueOf(size);}

}
-------------------------------------------
public class PizzaForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public PizzaForm() {
        initComponents();
        initiateComboBoxes();

    }
public void initiateComboBoxes(){
    cboSize.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(Size.values()));
}
---------------------------------------------
private void btnAddToOrderActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        //when button clicked..
        Pizza pizza=new Pizza(cboSize.getSelectedItem(),cboCrust.getSelectedItem(),cboSauce.getSelectedItem(),cboTopping1.getSelectedItem(),cboTopping2.getSelectedItem());
    }
```

the error is on the second to last line. It highlights my entire line with the error. Could anyone tell me what could be the problem? I'm not converting anything to 'Size' so I don't know what the problem is. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JComboBox#getSelectedItem()` is not "genericized" and so only knows to return raw Object type. You will need to cast the object returned from this method to the appropriate type, for example in this case Size.

So:

```
Pizza pizza = new Pizza((Size) cboSize.getSelectedItem(), 
                        (Crust) cboCrust.getSelectedItem(), 
                        (Sauce) cboSauce.getSelectedItem(), 
                        (Topping) cboTopping1.getSelectedItem(), 
                        (Topping) cboTopping2.getSelectedItem());
```

Comment: It's removed my error. I'll let you know tomorrow if it has sorted out my problem as I need to add the full features to my program